# access of undefined property event (how to call movie clip inside another )

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I appreciate anybody will answer me so so much

I am a beginner in flash and AS3 I try to implement some tutorials   from youtube.One of them this   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b3GWw5noCT4

I implement it step by step but there is a compiler error appears "access of undefined property event "

images_mc << I have only one movie clip in side it 6 pic without instance name.

```
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import flash.display.Shape;
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;


var imgBorder:Shape = new Shape();
imgBorder.graphics.lineStyle(5,0xffffff,1,true,"normal");
imgBorder.graphics.drawRect(0,0,250,120);
addChild(imgBorder);

imgBorder.visible = false;

images_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER , rolloverF);
images_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT , rolloutF);

function rolloverF(e:MouseEvent):void{
    imgBorder.visible = true;
    var borderTween:Tween = new Tween(imgBorder,"alpha",Strong.easeOut,0,1,1,true);
    var borderW:Tween = new Tween(imgBorder,"width",Strong.easeOut,255,280,1,true);
    var borderH:Tween = new Tween(imgBorder,"height",Strong.easeOut,125,137,1,true);
    //images_mc
    var imgW:Tween = new Tween(event.target,"width",Strong.easeOut,250,275,1,true);
    var imgH:Tween = new Tween(event.target,"height",Strong.easeOut,120,132,1,true);

    imgBorder.x = event.target.x;
    imgBorder.y = event.target.y;

    images_mc.setChildIndex(event.target as MovieClip, numChildren-1);

    }

function rolloutF(e:MouseEvent):void{
    var borderTweenBack:Tween = new Tween(imgBorder,"alpha",Strong.easeOut,1,0,1,true);
    var borderWBack:Tween = new Tween(imgBorder,"width",Strong.easeOut,280,255,1,true);
    var borderHBack:Tween = new Tween(imgBorder,"height",Strong.easeOut,137,125,1,true);


    var imgWBack:Tween = new Tween(event.target,"width",Strong.easeOut,275,250,1,true);
    var imgHBack:Tween = new Tween(event.target,"height",Strong.easeOut,132,120,1,true);

    }
```

Comment: I changed "e:MouseEvent" to "event:MouseEvent" but the error still appear any answer???

Comment: Have you changed it in both listeners, rolloverF and rolloutF? Also, you should run test the movie in debug mode to see at what line the error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments you said the error still persists. See image below, your code should look something like this on both functions like @Cristina said: If the code you've shown is the only code then it should have no issues otherwise it's possible that maybe something else you haven't shown is also causing issues. Debug with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER for better compiler feedback.

[image]

When I did a roll-over that line `images_mc.setChildIndex(event.target as MovieClip, numChildren-1);` gave an error but I think that's because my **images_mc** was empty anyway just for testing. The error was `"Index is out of bounds"` meaning non existant/available for access (as should be expected of an empty MC with no children added).

**PS**: The above should solve your "event" error but the other part of your questions was "..how to call movie clip inside another". Chain link the instance names to have a path address. For example to change width of pic5_mc inside Images_mc you would use `Images_mc.pic5_mc.width = 100;`

Comment: Oops my bad.. meant use `evt.currentTarget` but `evt.target` should work the same for you.

Comment: thanks a lot for your helpful explanation. Am really thank you a lot but how to solve this problem When I did a roll-over that line images_mc.setChildIndex(event.target as MovieClip, numChildren-1); gave an error but I think that's because my images_mc was empty anyway just for testing. The error was "Index is out of bounds" meaning non existant/available for access (as should be expected of an empty MC with no children added).

Answer (score 0):

For short, change "e:MouseEvent" to "event:MouseEvent".
For long, start not from tutorials, but from theory basics, like http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning.html . And stop coding in frame - thats the bad practice.

Comment: first thank you for your answer.second, be calm we here to learn not to fight.third the error  still appear!!!!!.